# Why is あります used in 「どうかあなたが幸せでありますように」?

Tags: song-lyrics

I’m trying to understand the line in bold from the song “Unlasting” by LiSA:

あなたの香りあなたの話し方
今も身体中に愛の欠片が残ってるよ
私の願い私の願いはただ
**どうかあなたが幸せでありますように**

What I don’t understand is the use of あります here. I think it can be translated as “Somehow you seem to be happy”. However, unless I miss something, あります(有る) should be used for inanimate objects while for animates one should use います(居る).

Thanks!

Comment: `while for animates one should use いります(居る)`  います, not いります.

Comment: You are right - I edited it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case you want to consider [であります](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%A7%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99) as a whole. であります means "to be or is" and is being applied to 幸せ (happiness). So 幸せであります is something like is happiness, be happiness, or etc in a literal sense. The [ように](https://www.kanshudo.com/grammar/%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB) here also signifies that this is intended as a wish or hope. Also the どうか at the beginning is like "please" or adds emphasis onto this wish or hope.

So this line is something like (without explicitly expressing どうか):

> どうかあなたが幸せでありますように
>
> I hope that you are happy

Explicitly expressing どうか as "truly"

> I truly hope that you are happy

Comment: How about the 「どうか」part? Any meaning it adds doesn't translate into English?

Comment: どうか in this case is like "please" or adds emphasis onto the wish that "you are happy". From an English perspective, depending on the context it could be translated into "please", "truly", "really", or etc.